# Three body problem with two fermions and a different particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm studying the three body problem with two fermions of unitary mass and another different particle. I need references of the HVZ theorem in this case. Is there someone who knows them?